# Add value to list using Provider package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier, showtimepicker

I want to insert a value from method `showTimePicker` to list in model class that extends ChangeNotifier.

```
void timePicker(){
    showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now()).then((value) {
      _timeOfDay = value!;
    Provider.of<GridWidgetModel(context,listen:true).addTimeList(value.format(context).toString());
    });
  }
```

```
class GridWidgetModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  final List<String> _timeList = ["11:25", "22:15"];
  UnmodifiableListView<String> get timeList => UnmodifiableListView(_timeList);
  get displayList => _timeList;

  void addTimeList(pickerValue){
    _timeList.add(pickerValue);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[example of UI layout in this app: there is a button that invokes `timePicker` method.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiXEw.png)

I've added sample values to the list to make sure that problem there is in the adding the value, not in the fetching data from model class.

Previously I solved that by simply declaring that list in the StatefulWidget, but I've decided to use Provider package for better state management when app grows up.

```
class _GridWidgetState extends State<GridWidget> {
 List timeList = [];
  TimeOfDay _timeOfDay = TimeOfDay.now();

  void _showTimePicker() {
    showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now())
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _timeOfDay = value!;
        timeList.add(value.format(context).toString());
      });
    });
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had to change `Provider.of<GridWidgetModel(context, listen:true)` to `false` because it doesn't need to rebuild the widget tree when updating the list in this context.